# Hive client not working

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

I tried to use hive from my local machine at my cluster nodes, but getting the following error

```
> ade:[ ashsshar_bda200olh ] [ashsshar@slc01nwj work]$ /bin/bash
> $SRCHOME/hadoop/3rdparty/cloudera/cdh3u3/hive-0.7.1-cdh3u3/bin/hive
> --config $T_WORK/hive_scratch/conf/ /ade/ashsshar_bda200olh/hadoop/3rdparty/cloudera/cdh3u3/hive-0.7.1-cdh3u3/bin/hive: line 68: [:
> /ade/ashsshar_bda200olh/bda/image/puppet/modules/.ade_path: binary
> operator expected
> /ade/ashsshar_bda200olh/hadoop/3rdparty/cloudera/cdh3u3/hive-0.7.1-cdh3u3/bin/hive: line 73: [:
> /ade/ashsshar_bda200olh/bda/image/puppet/modules/.ade_path: binary
> operator expected
> /ade/ashsshar_bda200olh/hadoop/3rdparty/cloudera/cdh3u3/hive-0.7.1-cdh3u3/bin/hive: line 79: [:
> /ade/ashsshar_bda200olh/bda/image/puppet/modules/.ade_path: binary
> operator expected Hive requires Hadoop 0.20.x (x >= 1). 'hadoop
> version' returned: Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.2.0 Subversion
> file:///data/1/jenkins/workspace/generic-package-centos64-5-5/topdir/BUILD/hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.2.0/src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common
> -r 8bce4bd28a464e0a92950c50ba01a9deb1d85686 Compiled by jenkins on Fri Feb 15 11:13:38 PST 2013 From source with checksum
> 3eefc211a14ac7b6e764d6ded2eeeb26
```

When i tried to do the same on cluster nodes its working fine I have been able to use hive
[

> 

```
root@NODE conf]# hive Logging initialized using configuration in
> jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-0.10.0-cdh4.3.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
> Hive history
> file=/tmp/root/hive_job_log_9e464dd7-8713-4d46-91a9-3a486920212d_1999869476.txt
> hive>
```

I am not sure why this is happening.

hadoop verson at my machine gives the following output ::

>

```
    ashsshar_bda200olh ] [ashsshar@slc01nwj work]$ hadoop version
  Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.2.0 Subversion file:///data/1/jenkins/workspace/generic-package-centos64-5-5/topdir/BUILD/hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.2.0/src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common
    > -r 8bce4bd28a464e0a92950c50ba01a9deb1d85686 Compiled by jenkins on Fri Feb 15 11:13:38 PST 2013 From source with checksum
    > 3eefc211a14ac7b6e764d6ded2eeeb26
```

Answer (score 0):

hive-0.7.1-cdh3u3 and Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.2.0 is incompatible. I suggest you to update hive to hive-0.10.0-cdh4.2.0.

Comment: To know the hive version i ran the following command on my client machine, which shows hive rpm is hive-0.10.0+67-1.cdh4.2.0.p0.10.el5
ade:[ ashsshar_bda200olh ] [ashsshar@slc01nwj hive]$ rpm -qa |grep hive
hive-0.10.0+67-1.cdh4.2.0.p0.10.el5

Comment: But why your log show `$T_WORK/hive_scratch/conf/ /ade/ashsshar_bda200olh/hadoop/3rdparty/cloudera/cdh3u3/hive-0.7.1-cdh3u3/bin/hive`